# HTML/CSS Type Over Video Slider

Tags: layout, video, type

I'm working on a project where the designer wants tailored and styled type (i.e. CSS) over a video that's in a slider. Along with a png logo.

Each video slider will have a different layout treatment.

I'm sure it's possible, although my concern are users that have enlarged type in order to better view text in their browsers. Wouldn't the layout fall apart if the type is enlarged or reduced?

Answer (score 2):

You should bring up the scenario to the designer. Sometimes if you are working with a designer with print background, they might not realize they don't have the same degree of control on the layout when working on the web. Content that gets displayed may vary depending on the user's browser settings or even content that the system puts in.

e.g. Sliders content often gets pulled from a content management system. How will the design handle type over the video when it's longer than what's shown on the mockup?

Another thing to ask is what percentage of your user base will enlarge type on screen? Is it a large enough portion for you to worry about this issue?